# Include one Maven assembly inside another?

Tags: maven-2

My project generates 3/4 assemblies, 3 jars and 1 war.[I need to use assemblies itself]
I need to include 2 of these assembly jars into my war.
How can I ensure that before assembly war creation , other 2 jars are created ?
Please respond

Comment: Could you provide the pom.xml file?

Comment: <plugin>
    

<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-4</version>
    <executions>
<execution>For jar1</execution>
<execution>For jar2</execution>
<execution>For jar3</execution>
<execution>For war</execution>

Answer (score 4):

You have three choices:

1. define all the assembly executions in one plugin configuration, and order them as needed.
   See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522778/maven-assembly-plugin-how-to-create-nested-assemblies/1524113#1524113) for more details.
2. Define an earlier phase for your jar assemblies so that they have all been packaged before the war is packaged.
3. Move the jar content into separate projects and specify them as dependencies of the war project so they are packaged automatically. This is the "Maven way" of handling this. It would also allow you to potentially reuse the jars in other wars.

I'd recommend option 3 myself, but the other two should both work.