# How to create and include a zip file inside a tar using maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project which is using a maven assembly plugin to include a bunch of files into a tar. Now I want to include a few more files in that tar, but first I want to zip them up and actually include that zip file.

I tried doing something like this: [maven-assembly plugin - how to create nested assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522778/maven-assembly-plugin-how-to-create-nested-assemblies)

So basically created 2 executions inside the maven assempbly plugin and have the first execution create the required zip file that the second execution can package into a tar.

But I get the error saying the zip file 'is not a file'.

What is wrong with what I am doing?
Is there a more efficient way to do this?

This is what I tried:
My POM:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-zip</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>zip.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-tar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>tar.xml</descriptor>d
                        </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions> 
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

zip.xml

```
<assembly xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>zip-id</id>
<formats>
    <format>zip</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/vertica_schema/schema_migrations</directory>
     <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

tar.xml

```
<assembly xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-  plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>tar-id</id>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<files> 
    <file>
        <source>/*.zip</source>
        <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
        <destName>schema_migrations.zip</destName>
    </file>
</files>
```

Comment: Change the `<source>` tag to `${project.basedir}/target/[name of zip file].zip`. You can't have `*` inside `<source>` and the zip built by the first execution will generate it inside `target`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can I change the name of the zip file being built in the first execution? I tried <destName> does not work.  Can i give the <outputdirectory> of the first execution as '${project.basedir}/src/main/....' or does it only have to be inside target? Also is there an efficient way to handle/delete the intermediary zip file created in the target ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<source>` tag does not support `*`: it is only possible to select a single file with it. Additionally, the zip file build by the first execution will be generated inside the [`target` folder by default](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html#outputDirectory), so you should point to that directory.

By default, the zip file will be named `${project.build.finalName}-zip-id.zip`. You can change this name by setting the [`finalName`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html#finalName) attribute in the plugin configuration. Note that, by default, the assembly id will be concatenated to the `finalName`. You can turn this off by switching the [`appendAssemblyId`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html#appendAssemblyId) flag to `false`.

This is a working configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-zip</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>zip.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <finalName>myzip</finalName> <!-- Name of zip file -->
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId> <!-- Do not concatenate "zip-id" to the finalName" -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-tar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>tar.xml</descriptor>d
                        </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions> 
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

with the following `tar.xml`:

```
<assembly xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-  plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>tar-id</id>
<formats>
    <format>tar.gz</format>
</formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
<files> 
    <file>
        <source>${project.basedir}/target/myzip.zip</source>
        <outputDirectory>/lib</outputDirectory>
        <destName>schema_migrations.zip</destName>
    </file>
</files>
```

It is a good practice to keep everything that is generated by Maven under the `target` directory. This is the working folder of Maven and you should not worry about keeping intermediate files in there.

Comment: I used <finalname> but the name of the zip file comes out as myzip-zip-id.zip. Am I missing a setting to stop maven from appending the descriptor id to the end of the file name?

Comment: I need to create another zip file the same way. Do I have to create another execution for it, or is there a way to leverage the existing zip execution?

Comment: @Gadam I edited my post to include the `appendAssemblyId` flag. You should create an execution per generated file (assembly).

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki, for the detailed and spot on answer!